# How can I configure rancher mongodb cluster with spring boot?

Tags: spring, mongodb, rancher

I have mongodb replicasets added as a stack in rancher.

I have configured link to the service as mongodb. But whenever I connected to database in spring boot application I got this exception:

```
    7/5/2016 6:57:24 AMcom.mongodb.MongoException: not talking to master and retries used up
    7/5/2016 6:57:24 AM at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:323) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.2.jar!/:na]
    7/5/2016 6:57:24 AM at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:325) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.2.jar!/:na]
    7/5/2016 6:57:24 AM at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:325) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.2.jar!/:na]
    7/5/2016 6:57:24 AM at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:273) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.2.jar!/:na]
    7/5/2016 6:57:24 AM at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:86) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.2.jar!/:na]
    7/5/2016 6:57:24 AM at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:68) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.2.jar!/:na]
    7/5/2016 6:57:24 AM at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:498) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.2.jar!/:na]
    7/5/2016 6:57:24 AM at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:621) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.2.jar!/:na]
    7/5/2016 6:57:24 AM at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:657) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.2.jar!/:na]
    7/5/2016 6:57:24 AM at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1943) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
```

Do I need to add any other configuration in my spring boot application to make it work.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do these changes, then it will work.

1. Pass the complete replica set string while connecting to the
   mongodb, do not pass an individual server IP
2. Change the readPreferance to PrimaryPrefferred, instead of Primary
   only.